# still have bugs when querying children().list().setQ() ？

Tags: google-drive-api

```
String  queryString2  = " title ='" + currentSubFolder+ "'";
　　　　　Children.List request_2 = service.children().list(mainFolder_Id).setQ(queryString2);
　　　　　ChildList files = request_2.execute();
```

it  will return

```
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563): {
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563):   "code": 500,
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563):   "errors": [
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563):     {
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563):       "domain": "global",
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563):       "message": "Internal Error",
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563):       "reason": "internalError"
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563):     }
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563):   ],
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563):   "message": "Internal Error"
08-15 00:18:10.656: W/System.err(12563): }
```

still have  bugs  in  java client api  not be fixxed?  But  I  tested  JAVASCRIPT  api  online  seems can  query  with  Query field  yesterday.